# psexec remote install from remote file

Tags: powershell, remote-server, psexec

I am trying to install an exe which is placed on a network share via psexec on a remote computer. Something like below

```
./Psexec \\remote-computer -h -u domain\username -p password CMD /C \\network-share\setup.exe
```

but I sometimes get the handle is invalid error or the access is denied.

Remote-computer and network share both are in same domain only and have the id with which I am trying also have complete access still not sure what's blocking.

Can somebody please advise.

Comment: What is the attribute /C for? Are you shure you didn't mean -c? `./Psexec \\remote-computer -h -u domain\username -p password CMD -c \\network-share\setup.exe` ?  - [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

Comment: /C is for current directory and -c is for copying the file if it's not present in the system path, I have tried them as well but no luck.